# Given that i have a 2d array and i want to reshape it to 1d with one value per row

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

This is my array

```
arr = np.array([[0, 1],
[3, 4],
[6, 7]])

flat_arr = np.reshape(arr, -1)
```

am getting the following result:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

my desired result is :

```
[0]
[1]
[3]
[4]
[5]...
```

Comment: `arr.reshape(-1,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it:

```
flat_arr[:, None]
flat_arr[:, np.newaxis]
np.expand_dims(flat_arr, axis=1)
```

Additionally, you could just reshape it like so:

```
arr.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this new shape:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 1], [3, 4], [6, 7]])

flat_arr = np.reshape(arr, (arr.shape[0] * arr.shape[1], 1))

print(flat_arr)
```

Output:

```
[[0]
 [1]
 [3]
 [4]
 [6]
 [7]]
```

Also, as @MarkMeyer has added, you could use:

```
flat_arr = np.reshape(arr, (-1, 1))
```