# How to plot a line with matplotlib which is given in linear algebra form?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

This is a trivial problem but I run into it again and again and I am sure there is a elegant solution, which I would like to use.

I do math with numpy and would like to plot lines that are results of linear algebra calculations. These lines come in the form
[image]

So I would would like to "outsource" the job of finding the start end endpoint of my line to a clever sipplet of python code, so that my resulting line gets drawn into my 3D plot, honoring the existing dimensions of the plot. E.g. if I plotted a 3D parabel from x = -2 to 2 and z = -3 to 3, and I wanted to draw a line
[image],
it would figure out that it would need to start at (-2,1,-2) and end at (2,1,2).

How could that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, it's important to define `projection` parameter. At second, you need to work with different shapes of `P`, `v` and `z` in order to obtain `X`, `Y`, `Z` parameters that corresponds to coordinates of `plot` method:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

P = np.array([1,1,1]).reshape(-1,1)
v = np.array([1,0,1]).reshape(-1,1)
z = np.linspace(-3,3,100)
X, Y, Z = P + v*z

ax.plot(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

#### Per comments

`reshape(-1, 1)` adds an [extra dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64454507/3044825) which is required for broadcasting (you can also read a [nice tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d) on this topic). It is also a substitute of `reshape(3, 1)`. Simple case (`arr1 = v`; `arr2 = np.linspace(-3,3,11)`) can be visualized like so:

[image]

Ending points of a curve `g = (1, 1, 1) + z * (1, 0, 1)` are at the bounds of interval of `z`, namely:

```
g1 = (1, 1, 1) + (-3) * (1, 0, 1) = (-2, 1, -2)
g2 = (1, 1, 1) + 3 * (1, 0, 1) = (4, 1, 4)
```

Note that `z = 1` is needed to get ending point = `(2,1,2)`

Comment: can you please explain what the reshape(-1,1) does? And what about the -3,3 range? That is obviously manual (which is not a major issue). But that is just a rough guess of the range we might be in, right?

Comment: @AndreasSchuldei Look at my update.In general, you can solve some equations to find a range required like in my example. One more to mention, `np.linspace(-3,3,2)` is enough because we need only two points to define a segment.